# Send child component as props in parents and add props to child component in parent method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am trying to add a component as a props in my parent component and then add props to the child component from the parent methods for instance:

```
function Parent(props) {
   const ParentChild = props.child;
   return ( 
      <ParentChild someprop=1 />
   )
}

function Child(props) {
    return <span>{props.someprop}</span>
}
```

And when creating the parents I do:

```
<Parent child={Child} />
```

This does not seems to work how can I do this? I am using React with TypeScript

Comment: Your `</span>` is not properly written

Comment: @testing_22 fixed it thanks!

Comment: How is this not working? What errors are you getting? Can you be more specific?
And also, `someprop=1`  needs to be `someprop={1}`